# Using UrlFetchApp in a container-bound script to run code in a web app as effective user

Tags: google-apps-script

In a little over my head. Trying to use UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options) from a container-bound script to run code in a web app.

The problem: Container-bound doc script can only run as the activeUser.  doc script creates a new doc by copying a template.  I would like the doc newly created from the template to be stored in a centralized folder owned by the developer.  I see two solutions.

1. I give all domain users view/edit access to the developer's folder.
2. I create a web app from a standalone script which runs as the effectiveUser (developer) who has access to the folder.  In this case the doc script calls the web app using UrlFetchApp passing in the parameters (folder, doc).  However,  to quite able to figure out how to do this, if possible.

   ```
   var unitId =  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
   var unit = DriveApp.getFileById(unitId);
   var folderId = unit.getDescription() //FoldId for unit is stored in description
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
   var lesson = DriveApp.getFileById(UNIT.LESSON_TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy('Lesson - ' + result.getResponseText());
   folder.addFile(lesson);//Currently I have the folder shared/edit with domain users.
                         //I would prefer to share/view. However, since the 
                         //container-bound doc script runs only as active user, no 
                         //can do.  Is it possible to build a small web app which 
                         //runs as effective user and saves lesson to folder. 

   showLessonSidebar(folderId);
   ```

   Any hints out there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a web app that runs as effective user.If the developer - effective user has access to folder and template file.

You could pass the folderId and Name of the file to be copied to the WebApp, rather than passing folder and Doc object (passing the folder Object and Doc object as URL parameter may be quite tricky and if content is too large may not be even possible as there are constraints on the possible length of URL)

1) Write a Apps Script

```
  function doGet(e) {
     var folderId = e.parameters.folderId;
     var copyFileName = e.parameters.name;
     var userEmail = e.parameters.email;
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
     var lesson = DriveApp.getFileById(UNIT.LESSON_TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(copyFileName);
     folder.addFile(lesson);
     //share file to domain or share folder with domain - folder.setSharing(....);
     file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  }
```

2) While deploying the Web App, developer can set Execute as me(developer@...) and set "Who has access to Web App" as Anyone.

3) Make sure developer has authorized the web App.

4) Share the Web App Script file with all your domain users.

Also, if you want to pass the content of file for some reason from container-script to Web App, you may consider implementing the logic in doPost() as you would have the ability to pass large data using POST in UrlFetch.

Comment: Thank you prasun. I was also having trouble constructing the UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options) call.  Would you have any hints on how that would be constructed?

Comment: How is your web app deployed (the one which you are invoking from UrlFetchApp) -to run always as the user who invokes it or the developer? Secondly, what error are you getting when using UrlFetchApp?

Comment: I would like the web app to be deployed as the developer (effectiveUser). I want to call it from a container-bound doc script and pass it the folderId and fileName.  I haven't been able to construct the UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options) call. It's a little too complicated for me.  I was hoping someone would be able to show me an example and maybe I could reverse engineer it to understand.

Comment: did you not read the example in [Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and go through list of Advanced params? Also See this [example](http://tech-nugget.blogspot.in/2011/10/google-apps-script-save-gmail.html).

Comment: I did. It was just a little over my head.

Comment: @user1472330 see the eaxmple link above in case it helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the only way to use `UrlFetch` in a bound script, is using an `installed trigger`. (`UrlFetch` is not authorized to run when used in a bound script's `simple triggers`: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#authorization_modes.)
An installed trigger always "runs with the authorization of the user who created the trigger, even if another user with edit access opens the spreadsheet". Thus, simply use [installed triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable):

```
function setupTrigger(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('open').forDocument(doc).onOpen().create();
}
```

This sample code creates an installable trigger for opening the document bound to the script.